# my character is not moving left or right. I cannot find the problem

Tags: javascript

So I am following a tutorial from internet  for a game. The problem is my character is not moving left or right. Here is the code:

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var interval;
var both = 0;

function moveLeft() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyvalue("left"));
  character.style.left = left - 2 + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyvalue("left"));
  character.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (both == 0) {
    both++;
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  both = 0;
});
```

```html
<div id="game">
  <div id="character"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your console is telling you what's wrong. `Uncaught TypeError: window.getComputedStyle(...).getPropertyvalue is not a function` --> `getPropertyValue()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPropertyvalue, like most names in js should have capital letters for every new word after the first (camel case),
Change it to getPropertyValue :)

```
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var interval;
var both = 0;

function moveLeft() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"));
  character.style.left = left - 2 + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  var left = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"));
  character.style.left = left + 2 + "px";
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (both == 0) {
    both++;
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      interval = setInterval(moveLeft, 1);
    }
    if (event.key === "ArrowRight") {
      interval = setInterval(moveRight, 1);
    }
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  both = 0;
});
```

Also, make sure your style is position:absolute

```
<div id="game">
  <div id="character" style="position:absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Of course this should be in css

Comment: I can't see your style, but set Position: absolute, I added this to the answer as well

Comment: Yo brother thanks for the help.....So your suggestion was right but the code still didnt work so i wrote it again from scratch :P and it worked fine.

Comment: There were 2 `getPropertyValue`s.. maybe you missed one?